# substituting spaces for underscores using lookaheads in perl

Tags: perl, regex-lookarounds, substitution

I have files with many lines of the following form:

```
word -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472 ....
```

(one word preceding several hundreds floats delimited by blanks)

Due to some errors out of my control, the word sometimes has spaces in it.

```
a bbb c -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472  .... (several hundreds floats)
```

which I wish to substitute by underscores so to get:

```
a_bbb_c -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472  .... (several hundreds floats)
```

have tried for each line the following substitution code:

```
s/\s(?=(\s-?\d\.\d+)+)/_/g;
```

So lookarounds is apparently not the solution.
I'd be grateful for any clues.

Comment: Is the number of float columns fixed? Can "a bbb c" contain digits?

Comment: Yes, it can also contain digits.

Comment: ... and the number of floats can vary, but it will be the same for any file treated.

Comment: Are all lines in your files always the same (i.e. a word followed by floats)? Is there a header first row (with columns names) from which you can deduce the number of columns?

Comment: Yes, there is such a header. I know the number of floats to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea for the lookahead is fine, but the question is how to replace only spaces in the part matched before the lookahead, when they are mixed with other things (the words, that is).

One way is to capture what precedes the first float (given by lookahead), and in the replacement part run another regex on what's been captured, to replace spaces

```
s{ (.*?) (?=\s+-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]) }{ $1 =~ s/\s+/_/gr }ex
```

Notes

- Modifier `/e` makes the replacement part be evaluated as code; any valid Perl code goes
- With `s{}{}` delimiters we can use `s///` ones in the replacement part's regex
- Regex in the replacement part, that changes spaces to `_` in the captured text, has `/r` modifier so to return the modified string and leave the original unchanged. Thus we aren't attempting to change `$1` (it's read only), and the modified string (being returned) is available as the replacement
- Modifier `/x` allows use of spaces in patterns, for readability
- Some assumptions must be made here. Most critical one is that the text to process is followed by a number in the given format, `-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`, and that there isn't such a number in the text itself.  This follows the OP's sample and, more decidedly, the attempted solution
- A couple of details with assumptions.  (1) Leading digits are expected with `[0-9]+\.` -- if you can have numbers like `.123` then use `[0-9]*\.` (2) The `\s+` in the inner regex collapses multiple consecutive spaces into one `_`, so `a  b c` becomes `a_b_c` (and not `a__b_c`)
- In the lookahead I scoop up all spaces preceding the first float with `\s+` -- and so they'll stay in front of the first float. This is as wanted with one space but with multiple ones it may be awkward

  If they were included in the `.*?` capture (if the lookahead only has one space, `\s`) then we'd get an `_` trailing the word(s). I thought that'd be *more* awkward.  The ideal solution is to run another regex and clean that up, if such a case is possible and if it's a bother

An example

```
echo "a bbb c -0.15636028 -0.2953045" |
    perl -wpe's{(.*?)(?=\s+-?[0-9]+\.[0-9])}{ $1 =~ s/\s+/_/gr }e'
```

prints

```
a_bbb_c -0.15636028 -0.2953045
```

---

Then to process all lines in a file you can do either

```
 perl -wpe'...' file > new_file
```

and get a `new_file` with changes, or

```
 perl -i.bak -wpe'...' file
```

to change the `file` *in-place* (that's `-i`), where `.bak` makes it save a backup.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. Thought I had a decent control of regexp and substitution, made me think again :-). And, needless to say, this actually works ...

Comment: @user3422424 Great, I'm glad if it helps.  I hope it's not too much "explanation" then :)   Let me know if there are questions, or if they pop up at any point.

Comment: Wow, had -1 (no clue why), now it's -2 ... ?  Seriously?

Comment: Nice answer. I could not figure out how to combine my two regex into one. Now I do. +1

Comment: @Andrey Thank you. Yeah, the `s///e` is a handy way for two-step processing -- capture suitably and then run code on that. (But one should keep in mind not to push that too far! :)

Comment: So this is **now at -3** and I've read it very carefully yet again and I don't get it.  Given that each answer on this page has multiple downvotes perhaps it's not about content?  If anyone sees reasons good enough to downvote please let me know so that I can improve it

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you:

```
s/\s+/_/g;
s/_(-?\d+\.)/ $1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to replace any spaces not followed by a float:

```
echo "a bbb cc  -0.123232 -0.3232" | perl -wpe 's/ +(?! *-?\d+\.)/_/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming from your comments your files look like that:

```
name float1 float2 float3
a bbb c -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472
abbb c -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472
a bbbc -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472
ab    bbc -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472
abbbc -0.15636028 -0.2953045 0.29853472
```

Since you said in comments that the first field may contain digits, you can't use a lookahead that searches the first float to solve the problem. (you can nevertheless use a lookahead that counts the number of floats until the end of the line but it isn't very handy).

What I suggest is a solution based on fields number defined by the header first line.

You can use the header line to know the number of fields and replace spaces at the begining of other lines until the number of fields is the same.

You can use perl command line as awk like that:

```
perl -MEnglish -pae'$c=scalar @F if ($NR==1);for($i=0;$i<scalar(@F)-$c;$i++){s/\s+/_/}' file
```

The for loop counts the difference between the number of fields in the first row (stored in `$c`) and in the current line (given by `scalar(@F)` where `@F` is the fields array), and repeats the substitution.

The `a` switches the perl command line in autosplit mode and the -MEnglish makes available the *number row* variable  as `$NR` (like the NR variable in awk).

It's possible to shorten it like that:

```
perl -pae'$c=@F if $.<2;$i=@F-$c;s/\s+/_/ while $i--' file
```

Comment: @ikegami: note that I already asked in comments if there's a header line at the start of the files and if each file has the same number of fields for each line. The answers was both positive. About eventual consecutive spaces, it's really a detail, that doesn't appear in the example string and that is really easy to solve.

Comment: @ikegami: About downvotes I suppose that people unable to fully read an answer has tested the command line with the example row without to understand that the header line is needed to make it work.

Comment: So at worst, it assumes that the header line isn't well formatted too? In this case, how user3422424 can say *"I know the number of floats to expect"*? He invents it or he declares it? Whatever it is a better solution than a lookahead since the first field can contain digits.

Comment: *"more than once space"*, in other words, consecutive spaces in the first field: you only have to add the `+` quantifier to solve it.

Comment: It isn't the question or in the example string, but why not.

Comment: No mention of them being consecutive too as you can see in the example string. And in my opinion about common mistakes in csv, not specialy realistic too.

Comment: The only problem with this topic is the asker mutism about the different suggested answers.